# Spark Streaming Kinesis missing records

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I have a spark streaming job that reads from several kinesis streams and unions them together in a single streaming context.

```
val streams = ingestionStreams.map(streamName => {
  KinesisInputDStream.builder.checkpointAppName(s"${jobName}_$streamName")
    .streamName(streamName)
    .streamingContext(ssc)
    .endpointUrl(endpointUrl)
    .regionName(regionName)
    .initialPositionInStream(InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON)
    .checkpointInterval(kinesisCheckpointInterval)
    .storageLevel(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
    .buildWithMessageHandler(KinesisRecordHandler.recordHandler)
})

import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
ssc.union(streams)
  .checkpoint(batchInterval)
  .foreachRDD(jsonRdd => ...)
```

I see correct numbers of records within the Spark Streaming tab in the UI. However the number of actual records processed by `foreachRDD` is less.

Within the executor logs I see many `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` however this *should* be benign in that the KCL should retry those records.

Unfortunately I am not seeing the missing records processed at a later date. Where to look next?